# Angular canActivate preload template

Tags: angular

I use `canActivate` to secure access to my application. The one who causes problem is the LoginRequired (code below) :

```
export class LoginRequiredService {

constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private notify: NotificationService,
    private translate: TranslateService,
) {
}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.authService.getToken()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        this.translate.get('AUTH.not_connected').subscribe((translated: string) => {
            this.authService.setCachedUrl(state.url.replace(/^\//g, ''));
            this.notify.error(translated)
            this.authService.logout()
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

The problem is, before redirect me (in the authService.logout() call) the template of the desired route is loaded and it causes me error because some variable aren't loadded because I'm not logged in

How could I improve that to avoid the template loading if the loginRequired redirect me to login ?

EDIT :

Here is a route example :

```
{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent , data: {title: marker('GLOBAL.home')}, canActivate: [LoginRequiredService]},
```

thanks

Comment: CanActivate prevents to load anything if not true. Add to your service class `implements CanActivate`, if it not helps, show how do you use your guard in routes.

Comment: My service implement the CanActivate, but same issue. I post a route example in the first post

Comment: Since you're calling observable, return a promise that resolves to true

Comment: @NathanCheval can you do your example in stackblitz ? it would be more helpful.

Comment: @NathanCheval problem is that before .subscribe() gets finishes execution, you are returning false, .subscribe() is async code, so you need to change first this, second instead .subscribe() you can use .map() pipe and return whole pipe() with Observable<boolean>

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that. One common way is to make a new interceptor (for e.g: AuthInterceptor) and in that return true all the time. Now include this interceptor in the auth module (or the modules which don't require login), this way the AuthInterceptor will override the interceptor used in the overall application.

Thanks